# Imprimir una columna de un csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Tengo un csv file varias columnas. Lo simplifico en el siguiente caso con dos.

```
ID     texto
1      Los niños comen sardinas
2      Los pájaros vuelan alto porque tienen alas
3      Érase una vez la vida
4      Un 67% de los adultos vive en la pobreza
```

Quiero imprimir solo la columna "texto". Y no lo consigo.
He probado mil maneras:

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['ID', 'texto']

df = pd.read_csv('Libro1.csv', usecols=fields)
# See the keys
print (df.keys())
# See content in 'ID' y 'texto'
print (df.texto)
```

Error:

```
raise ValueError("Usecols do not match names.")
ValueError: Usecols do not match names.
```

Otra:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('Libro1.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k

print(columns[0])
```

Ninguno de esto métodos me extrae

Comment: Hola pyring. El csv tal y como lo muestras es poco estándar ¿Cuál es el separador entre los datos de las diferentes columnas? En todo caso debería ser una tabulación pero aparentemente es un numero variable de espacios...

Comment: Hola. Son puntos y comas ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de que tienes un csv como el siguiente:

> ID;texto
>   1;Los niños comen sardinas
>   2;Los pájaros vuelan alto porque tienen alas
>   3;Érase una vez la vida
>   4;Un 67% de los adultos vive en la pobreza

Debes indicar el separador de forma adecuada:

```
import pandas as pd

fields = ['ID', 'texto']
df = pd.read_csv('Libro1.csv', usecols=fields,  sep=';')
```

O con el módulo csv:

```
with open('Libro1.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,  delimiter = ";")
    for row in reader:
        print (row["texto"]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla. Como siempre en el clavo. No obstante, mi csv file parece raro, y me da un error que es el siguiente: newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: pyring es un problema de encoding, sería necesario saber qué codificación se usó cuando se creo en el csv.  Si no lo creastes tu prueba a abrirlo con un editor como Atom  a ver si te autodetecta la codificación correctamente o si cambiándola manualmente das con una que te muestre correctamente el texto.

Comment: No sé si sirve de algo pero la codificación parece ser algo como: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: Piring esa línea de shebang se usa para indicar que el código de tu .py debe tratarse como texto utf-8. Además de esto debes guardar el .py con esa codificación. Con codificación usada me refiero al csv no al .py. ¿Has creado tu el archivo?¿Con qúe editor o código? Es posible que si pudieras subir el archivo csv a Dropbox o GogleDrive para poder reproducir el problema y ver si descubrimos la codificación.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla. No he creado yo el archivo. Y muy lamentablemente no puedo compartirlo porque contiene datos personales... En ocasiones al imprimir me intenta imprimir el texto pero aparece otro error: 
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5028: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Pyring pues entonces la clave está en intentar saber que codificación tiene ese csv. Como digo puedes intentarlo con algún editor, aunque no lo parezca no es tan trivial como parece. Luego abre el archivo indicando la codificación: `with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`, `with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as csvfile:`,  `with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='Latin-1') as csvfile:`,  etc

Comment: Estoy intentando esto, pero nada: import csv
import codecs
with codecs.open("scraped.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter = ";")
    for row in reader:
        print(row["text-pros"])

Comment: Piring como te digo el problema es que no tenemos ni idea de que codificación se usó para guardar el CSV. Podrias crear una copia del csv (copiar el archivo no seleccionar el texto y copiar en uno en blanco), luego en un editor de texto buscas el carácter 5028, eliminas todas las filas menos la que contiene ese carácter y esa fila la modificas  (no ese carácter) de forma que no des datos personales, guárdalo y subelo a ver si te podemos ayudar a descubrir el encoding. Sin poder reproducir nada es muy difícil, dentro de que ya es difícil adivinar la codificación de un archivo.